# Combine two class div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to combine two div classes together so it will work. Link : [I cant combine this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_image_overlay_icon) and this [I have done this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_shake_image.asp). I am trying to combine those things together,but I can't.How can I do that?The only it works is shake the image,I want both to be together work.I put now the .overlay from link one into the auto style3.

the css code is

```
img:hover {
  animation: shake 0.2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes shake {
  0% { transform: translate(1px, 1px) rotate(0deg); }
  10% { transform: translate(-1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg); }
  20% { transform: translate(-3px, 0px) rotate(1deg); }
  30% { transform: translate(3px, 2px) rotate(0deg); }
  40% { transform: translate(1px, -1px) rotate(1deg); }
  50% { transform: translate(-1px, 2px) rotate(-1deg); }
  60% { transform: translate(-3px, 1px) rotate(0deg); }
  70% { transform: translate(3px, 1px) rotate(-1deg); }
  80% { transform: translate(-1px, -1px) rotate(1deg); }
  90% { transform: translate(1px, 2px) rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: translate(1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg); }
}




.auto-style3 {
    margin-top: 0px;
     position: absolute; 
  bottom: 0; 
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); /* Black see-through */
  color: #f1f1f1; 
  width: 100%;
  transition: .5s ease;
  opacity:0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;

}




.auto-style4 {
    background-color: #FF0000;
}







* {box-sizing: border-box;}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 300px;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}



.container:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

and the code that I have in  is

```
 <div class="container"  >
    
  <img src="avatar.jpg" alt="Avatar" width="278" height="262" class="style3" >
  <div class="auto-style3">
  Avatar is ON
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: What did you attempt when you added them together?

Comment: I wanted both to be seemed the shaking and the black message. The only it seems is the shaking. I think I need to do something like this to make it work div class=" container ","overlay"

Comment: What did you do? Can you add it to the post?

Comment: the shaking only . I didn't manage it to do both work.I want to make them work in the same image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a straight copy/paste from both sources, then changed the first line of CSS in the snippet below (`img:hover` -> `.container:hover`)

```css
.container:hover {
  /* Start the shake animation and make the animation last for 0.5 seconds */
  animation: shake 0.5s;

  /* When the animation is finished, start again */
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes shake {
  0% { transform: translate(1px, 1px) rotate(0deg); }
  10% { transform: translate(-1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg); }
  20% { transform: translate(-3px, 0px) rotate(1deg); }
  30% { transform: translate(3px, 2px) rotate(0deg); }
  40% { transform: translate(1px, -1px) rotate(1deg); }
  50% { transform: translate(-1px, 2px) rotate(-1deg); }
  60% { transform: translate(-3px, 1px) rotate(0deg); }
  70% { transform: translate(3px, 1px) rotate(-1deg); }
  80% { transform: translate(-1px, -1px) rotate(1deg); }
  90% { transform: translate(1px, 2px) rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: translate(1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg); }
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .3s ease;
  background-color: red;
}

.container:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}

.icon {
  color: white;
  font-size: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.fa-user:hover {
  color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" class="image">
  <div class="overlay">
    <a href="#" class="icon" title="User Profile">
      <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```